# Prove an inequality in the Sobolev space

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $2\le p<\infty$, $U\subset \mathbb R^n$ being bounded with $C^1$ boundary, and $u\in W^{2,p}(U)\cup W^{1,p}_0(U)$. (I guess this is a typo in my textbook and it should be $u\in W^{2,p}(U)\cap W^{1,p}_0(U)$.)

The inequality to be proved is $$\int_U|Du|^pdx\le C \left(\int_U|u|^pdx\right)^{1\over2} \left(\int_U|D^2u|^pdx\right)^{1\over2}.$$

I was told to use integration by parts to prove this inequality. But there is only one term on the left-hand side, and there is no "parts" to integrate. I am really confused now.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you solved it in the case $p=2$?

Comment: @UmbertoP. Sorry I didn't... And I don't even know how to generalize the case $2<p<\infty$ if we have proved the case $p=2$... Can you explain it a bit? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case $p=2$ you have
$$\int_U |Du|^2 \, dx = \sum_{k=1}^n \int_U u_{x_k}^2 \, dx.$$
You can integrate by parts to obtain
$$\int_U u_{x_k}^2 \, dx = \int_U u_{x_k} u_{x_k} \, dx = - \int_U u \, u_{x_k x_k} \, dx$$
and apply Cauchy-Schwarz to get
$$
- \int_U u \, u_{x_k x_k} \, dx \le \left( \int_U |u|^2 \, dx \right)^{1/2} \left( \int_U |u_{x_k x_k}|^2 \, dx \right)^{1/2} \le \left( \int_U |u|^2 \, dx \right)^{1/2} \left( \int_U |D^2 u|^2 \, dx \right)^{1/2}.$$

After you return to the original sum the inequality holds with $C=n$.

---

If $p > 2$ the details are messier so I will just get it started.  Note that $$|Du|^p = |Du|^{p-2} |Du|^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n |Du|^{p-2} u_{x_k}^2= \sum_{k=1}^n |Du|^{p-2} u_{x_k}u_{x_k}.$$ Integration by parts gives you
$$ \int_U |Du|^{p-2} u_{x_k}u_{x_k} \, dx = - \int_U u \left(|Du|^{p-2} u_{x_k} \right)_{x_k} \, dx.$$
You need to estimate the last term.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't realize that $|Du|^2$ is a sum... thanks again

Comment: It's a convenient trick to use when working out inequalities. Glad to help.

Comment: Hi Umberto, when I tried to estimate the last term, I met a problem. I tried to use the Holder inequality but then I found I would get things like $\left( \int_U |u|^p dx\right)^{1\over p}\left( \int_U |\left(|Du|^{p-2} u_{x_k} \right)_{x_k}|^q \, dx\right)^{1\over q},$ where $q$ is the conjugate of $p$. So the problem is the power of integrals on the R.H.S are not $2$... And the power of $u_{x_k x_k}$ will be $pq-2q\,(=p-q)$... How can we resolve this?

Comment: ops the power of $u_{x_k x_k}$ would be $q$, not $p-q$. Sorry for that typo.